# c# close form change values open new form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing an application that asks for an input to be selected from a ComboBox then asks for a second input to be selected from another ComboBox (based on the first, there are different possibilities for each first input.) When both inputs are set, the user hits a button which passes these inputs to a second form and uses a `form2.show()` to open it (inputs are passed via properties). What I would like is to be able to close this new form (this functionality is done) and then select new inputs and have it open the second form again, this time using the new inputs. The inputs change what information is called on the new form. Right now, my program crashes when I hit the button to open the new form after changing the inputs.

Any suggestions?!

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here's the error I'm getting:
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Form2'.

And the code.

From the main form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        report_form.TypeSelected = type_selected;
        report_form.LoadSelected = load_selected;
        report_form.Show();
    }
```

From the child form:

```
public string TypeSelected { get; set; }
public string LoadSelected { get; set; }
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = "Report for " + TypeSelected + " load " + LoadSelected;
        label1.Text = "Type: " + TypeSelected;
        label2.Text = "Load: " + LoadSelected;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
        GetData();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Without seeing your code this is anybody guess

Comment: And please show the error. Though I'll guess that it's a Form Disposed...

Comment: You either have to call `this.Hide();` instead of `this.Close();` or recreate the report_form object with `new` before you can access those properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code it looks like you are probably showing the child form multiple times. When you call close, the form is DIsposed and calling show on it again without reinstantiating it will cause that exception. You either need to just hide your child form instead of closing it or if you close it, recreate it every time you want to show it. ([Hide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.hide.aspx) instead of Close.)

Also, you could consider using [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) for your child form. This is the preferred method for collecting data if you do not want or need the user to work with the parent form... It greatly simplifies how you interact with the child form.

High horse: You should try to refactor your application into [MVC (model, view controller.)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383153/The-Model-View-Controller-MVC-Pattern-with-Csharp) The controller class would decide what Forms load open and when and also pass the model (the data) between them. This kind of separation of concerns will greatly help you organize your app and get away from your issue. Or MVP too: ([Model View Presenter](http://www.cerquit.com/blogs/post/MVP-Part-I-e28093-Building-it-from-Scratch.aspx))

Comment: @user2196809 Remember to up-vote if you think Paul's answer helps the others in the future.  It signals the question and answer as helpful to future users.  Also his answer was very concise and well-informed.